# Select 2 ultimos registros da tabela Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Possuo uma tabela com os seguintes campos.

```
IMEI | TimeStamp | Value
123  | 1570011000| 1
123  | 1570012800| 0
123  | 1570015200| 1
123  | 1570017000| 0
```

Gostaria de pegar os 2 últimos registros e fazer a diferença entre o Timestamp dos 2 últimos registros.

Pensei em fazer um select para cada registro:

```
select value, TimeStamp from myTable where TimeStamp = (select max(TimeStamp) from myTable) and value ='1' 

select value, TimeStamp from myTable where TimeStamp = (select max(TimeStamp) from myTable) and value ='0'
```

Porém no primeiro select não tenho retorno (simplesmente não me retorna nada e não da erro)

Já no segundo select ele me retorno corretamente.

Como poderia fazer isso ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua coluna de *timestamp* pode até ser considerada chave, já que muito provavelmente nunca se repetirá.

A consulta da forma que está vai pegar sempre o maior tempo (`(select max(TimeStamp) from myTable)`), e ele sempre será `value` **0** ou **1**; por isso tem retorno em apenas uma das consultas.

Tente assim:

```
select value, TimeStamp 
from myTable 
where TimeStamp = (select max(TimeStamp) from myTable where value ='1')

select value, TimeStamp 
from myTable 
where TimeStamp = (select max(TimeStamp) from myTable where value ='0')
```

Comment: Sim, agora esta funcionando bem, obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 2):

> Gostaria de pegar os 2 últimos registros e fazer a diferença entre o
>   Timestamp dos 2 últimos registros.

Considerando que sempre terá na ordem `0` e `1` em `value`, então você pode fazer por *sub-query* já fazendo a subtração:

```
SELECT
((SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM tabela_a WHERE value = 1) - 
(SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM tabela_a WHERE value = 0))
AS diferenca
```

Isso lhe trará já o valor da diferença. Se caso não é isso que quer, então sua pergunta está errada.